# Multiple checkboxes update in DB with ENUM and Custom column

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, pdo, enums

I have an table where custom columns where made by administrators, every column have hiis own enum with '0','1'. Here you can choose if the column is true or false.

Now i want te make a option where administrators can update this true or false by a checkbox.

The Checkbox.

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <?php
    if(isset($produci[0])) {
    foreach($produci as $key => $avlue) {
    ?>
    <div class="row-fluid">
       <label>
           <input name="clickedproduct[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $avlue['name']; ?>" <?php echo (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') ? ((isset($_POST[$avlue['name']])) ? ' value="'.$avlue[$avlue['name']].'" checked' : ' value="'.$avlue[$avlue['name']].'"') : (($avlue[$avlue['name']] == '1') ? ' value="'.$avlue[$avlue['name']].'"checked' : ' value="'.$avlue[$avlue['name']].'"')); ?>>
           <?php echo $avlue['name']; ?>
      </label>                                    
    </div> 
    <?php } }else{
                  echo '<font color="red">Er zijn nog geen producten aangemaakt.</font>';
                 } ?>                           
</div>
```

My PDO.

```
if(isset($_POST['clickedproduct']))
  {  $values = array();
  foreach($_POST['clickedproduct'] as $access )
  { 
    $clickedproduct = '0'; // = bijv. 1 of 0
    $column = $access; // = bijv. product
  } // end of foreach.


    $product_access = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE products_access SET `{$column}` = :enum WHERE products_access.id = :id");
    $product_accessvar = trim($user['id']);
    $product_access->bindParam(':id', $product_accessvar, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $product_access->bindParam(':enum', $clickedproduct, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
    $product_access->execute();
}
```

Is there someone with an solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should toggle your ENUM column by below way.

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = IF(column_name=1, 0, 1);
```

In your code,

```
$sql = "UPDATE products_access SET  `{$column}` = IF( `{$column}`=1, 0, 1) WHERE products_access.id = :id";
$product_access = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$product_accessvar = trim($user['id']);
$product_access->bindParam(':id', $product_accessvar, PDO::PARAM_INT);
//$product_access->bindParam(':enum', $clickedproduct, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$product_access->execute();
```

Comment: I have edit your code a little, but i have now the problem that the column enum change to 0 when it is 1 but, when it is 1 he will delete the enum and give me nothing.

Comment: There is a problem, the checkbox need to be checked if it is checked or not, because now when it is select he will check it is true or false and change it when it is equal.